# SQL Multiple Sequences Unique per Store

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sequence

I have a table which contains loans. These loans come from different stores, the stores are in different states.

There is a state requirement that each store location must have a unique numeric code for the loan and that the sequence must not have any gaps. Since this data is in a consolidated table, I was looking for a way to assign a specific sequence for each store. The contents of the sequence may be duplicated across stores, that is, store 10 may have a sequence value of 10 for a transaction as well as store 15.

I know that I could use a trigger after insert to look for the last number used for a store and increment it by one, but was looking for something a bit more elegant and error resistant to accomplish this

Comment: Is this a one-time issue for reporting?  Or is this a requirement for an ongoing assignment of the numbers?  The state requirement seems quite arcane, but the law is the law.

Comment: Ongoing as new records were inserted

Comment: Your only choice may be to use a trigger or to wrap all inserts into the table in a stored procedure that does essentially the same thing (this is the approach I would take).

Comment: Pretty much figured that but thought that I would refer it to the collective mind before finalizing on an approach. Thanks for validating my thought

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence!

```
CREATE SEQUENCE loans.StateOfXYLoanNum
    START WITH 100000
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
```

Your program, a trigger, or a manual intervention would be needed to grab the next value and insert it into a table.

More here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use a sequence for this . . . remember, there are legal requirements here.  Sequences can have gaps; here is one example from the documentation: "Gaps can still occur if numbers are requested using the NEXT VALUE FOR or sp_sequence_get_range functions, but then the numbers are either not used or are used in uncommitted transactions."  Unfortunately, for this type of requirement rather expensive locking is needed to ensure the appropriate enumeration.